# Python dict / OrderedDict: Assign function to value without executing it immediately

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have an OrderedDict whose values I would like to be functions, but have encountered unexpected behaviour. Initializing:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

options_dict=OrderedDict(["A",call_func_A(arg1,arg2)],
                         ["B",call_func_B(arg1,arg3)],
                         ["C",call_func_C(arg1,arg4)]

# Select options
options=["A","C"]

# Execute
result={}
for opt in options:
    result[opt]=options_dict[opt]

# Return result (or whatever)
print result
```

Functions call_func_A, call_func_B and call_func_C turn out to be executed when options_dict is declared, rather than in the subsequent for loop over options.

I'd like the function calls to wait until the for loop.

What's going on?

Comment: `call_func_A` is the function, `call_func_A(arg1,arg2)` is calling the function

Answer (score 4):

The functions are called before the dictionary is created. You made the call.

However, you can defer the function calls by nesting it within another function to be called later:

```
options_dict = OrderedDict([("A", lambda: call_func_A(arg1,arg2)),
                            ("B", lambda: call_func_B(arg1,arg3)),
                            ("C", lambda: call_func_C(arg1,arg4))])

# Select options
options = ["A", "C"]

# Execute
result = {}
for opt in options:
    result[opt] = options_dict[opt]() # <- call
```

The same effect can be achieved with [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial), with an extra `import` statement to execute.

On another note, since your function arguments are presumably **invariant**, I don't think when the calls are made is important here. You might as well keep your initial approach of having the functions called at the dict creation time.

Comment: The reason for deferring is that being relatively expensive I only want to call a subset (in order). Perhaps there is an easier way.

Comment: At the moment I get TypeError: expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Comment: @jtlz2 The code Moses Koledoye has provided is correct. The problem is in how you create the OrderedDict. Check out the first part of my answer for the correct way.

Comment: @jtlz2 That's coming from how you defined your `OrderedDict`. I have that fixed in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are declaring the OrderedDict incorrectly. The constructor expects a list of tuples. Instead, you are giving it multiple lists. Do it like so:

```
options_dict=OrderedDict([("A",call_func_A(arg1, arg2)),
                          ("B",call_func_B(arg1, arg3)),
                          ("C",call_func_C(arg1, arg4))])
```

Second, when you declare `options_dict`, you don't pass the functions as the values of the dict, but rather their results:

```
options_dict=OrderedDict(["A",call_func_A(arg1,arg2)],
                         ["B",call_func_B(arg1,arg3)],
                         ["C",call_func_C(arg1,arg4)])
```

You are *calling them* by doing `call_func_A(arg1, arg2)`. One relatively simple way of avoiding that is by omitting the args:

```
options_dict=OrderedDict([("A",call_func_A),
                         ("B",call_func_B),
                         ("C",call_func_C)])
```

You can store the args in a second OrderedDict:

```
args_dict=OrderedDict([("A",[arg1, arg2]),
                      ("B",[arg3, arg4]),
                      ("C",[arg5, arg6])])
```

And then to call them:

```
result={}
for opt in options:
    result[opt]=options_dict[opt](*args_dict[opt])
```